# Executing VBA Macro in Excel file using SSIS (Visual Studio)

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2012, ssis, vba

I am trying to create an SSIS package that will enable me to open Excel files (.xls) and then using a Script Task (or a better method if anyone knows), I would like to open the Excel file, run a Macro from my PersonalWorkbook.xlsb and the save the excel file and close it.

So far the code I have found to use is this :

`

```
  Imports System
   Imports System.Data
   Imports System.Math
    Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
   Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

   _
   _
 Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum


' The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
' To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, 
events,
' and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown 
in the following examples.
'
' To reference a variable, call 
Dts.Variables("MyCaseSensitiveVariableName").Value
' To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, Nothing)
' To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the 
help message", "", 0, True)
'
' To use the connections collection use something like the following:
' ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB")
' cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial 
Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto 
Translate=False;"
'
' Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to 
indicate success or failure.
' 
' To open Help, press F1.


Public Sub Main()



    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing

    Try


        'Start Excel and open the workbook.
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.Visible = False
        oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
        oBook = 
 oBooks.Open(Dts.Variables("Det_Sign_DestFileName").Value.ToString()) ' 
 Change your variable name here.


        'Run the macros.
        'oExcel.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!TriangleDetail") ' Change the name of your Macro here.


        'Clean-up: Close the workbook and quit Excel.
        oBook.Save()
        oExcel.Quit()



        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

    Finally
        If oBook IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook)
        If oBooks IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks)
        If oExcel IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel)


        oBook = Nothing
        oBooks = Nothing
        oExcel = Nothing

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

`

It has no errors when I close VSTA, however, when I excecute the ssis package in Visual Studio I get this error here :

"DTS Script Task has encountereed an exception in user code:

Project name: ST_bf96275780f942c49789ab24ddab12da

Cannot load script for execution.

(With a blank box not indicating any errors)"

Could I please have help wit this or could someone advise me of a full-proof easy way to run VBA Macros from my PersonalWorkbook.xlsb on other excel files using a script task (or otherwise) in an ssis package.

I  am using Visual Studio 2012 , SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft Excel 2013.